# Cake php Datasource class MySQL could not be found

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pdo, datasource

I have ubuntu 10.04 on server.
I am trying to set up the cake php project but it gives me following error

```
   Cake is NOT able to connect to the database.

   Datasource class MySQL could not be found.
```

I have searched lot on the web regarding it.
my config file looks like this

```
  class DATABASE_CONFIG {

public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/MySQL',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => 'mypassword',
    'database' => 'dbname',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
 }
```

I checked that server has all the things set up to connect as PDO I have run following script and it works fine.

```
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', $username, $password);
```

Then further I have changed in Mysql.php file of cake php which is in the "lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\Database"

I tried to give static connection in Mysql.php but this also doesn't work. I did exit in the Mysql.php and seems like control of page is not getting here.

```
    $this->_connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', $username, $password);
$this->connected = true;
```

Please do let me know if I am missing anything.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Casing matters, it should be:

```
'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql'
```

And not:

```
'datasource' => 'Database/MySQL'
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysql is not a supported source try 'datasource' => 'Database/Sqlite',